# Error: Inconsistent with 'net' object

Tags: verilog

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to simulate my testbench on ModelSim. I'm just in the early stage of the testbench, and I'm just adding some values to a variable when this error appears. 
I have instantiated the topmodule and created the DUT for it in the testbench. Using the instance I'm going in the hierarchy where I get my desired variable that I want to assign a value. 
I have googled for an answer to this question and the only thing I have found is that I cannot make a procedural assignment to a wire. The thing is that that the variable in question is an input, not a wire.

The project I'm working on is based on the openRISC 1200 architecture. I could not find any testbench that worked properly, that's why I'm trying to write my own.

Below is the testbench code:

```
module testbenchOR (
); 
reg cmd;   
reg rst;
reg clk; 

//----------------------TOP-LEVEL--------------------------------------
wire            iwb_cyc_o;  // cycle valid output
wire    [31:0]  iwb_adr_o;  // address bus outputs
wire            iwb_stb_o;  // strobe output
wire            iwb_we_o;   // indicates write transfer
wire    [3:0]       iwb_sel_o;  // byte select outputs
wire    [31:0]  iwb_dat_o;  // output data bus
wire            dwb_cyc_o;  // cycle valid output
wire    [31:0]  dwb_adr_o;  // address bus outputs
wire            dwb_stb_o;  // strobe output
wire            dwb_we_o;   // indicates write transfer
wire    [3:0]       dwb_sel_o;  // byte select outputs
wire    [31:0]  dwb_dat_o;  // output data bus
wire    [3:0]       dbg_lss_o;  // External Load/Store Unit Status
wire    [1:0]       dbg_is_o;   // External Insn Fetch Status
wire    [10:0]      dbg_wp_o;   // Watchpoints Outputs
wire            dbg_bp_o;   // Breakpoint Output
wire    [31:0]  dbg_dat_o;  // External Data Output
wire            dbg_ack_o;  // External Data Acknowledge (not WB compatible)
wire    [3:0]       pm_clksd_o;
wire            pm_dc_gate_o;
wire            pm_ic_gate_o;
wire            pm_dmmu_gate_o;
wire            pm_immu_gate_o;
wire            pm_tt_gate_o;
wire            pm_cpu_gate_o;
wire            pm_wakeup_o;
wire            pm_lvolt_o;
reg         clk_i;
reg         rst_i;
reg [1:0]       clmode_i;   // 00 WB=RISC, 01 WB=RISC/2, 10 N/A, 11 WB=RISC/4
reg [19:0]  pic_ints_i;
reg         iwb_clk_i;  // clock input
reg         iwb_rst_i;  // reset input
reg         iwb_ack_i;  // normal termination
reg         iwb_err_i;  // termination w/ error
reg         iwb_rty_i;  // termination w/ retry
reg [31:0]  iwb_dat_i;  // input data bus
reg         dwb_clk_i;  // clock input
reg         dwb_rst_i;  // reset input
reg         dwb_ack_i;  // normal termination
reg         dwb_err_i;  // termination w/ error
reg         dwb_rty_i;  // termination w/ retry
reg [31:0]  dwb_dat_i;  // input data bus
reg         dbg_stall_i;    // External Stall Input
reg         dbg_ewt_i;  // External Watchpoint Trigger Input
reg         dbg_stb_i;      // External Address/Data Strobe
reg         dbg_we_i;       // External Write Enable
reg [31:0]  dbg_adr_i;  // External Address Input
reg [31:0]  dbg_dat_i;  // External Data Input
reg         pm_cpustall_i;

or1200_top TOP_LEVEL(
    .iwb_cyc_o(iwb_cyc_o),
    .iwb_adr_o(iwb_adr_o),
    .iwb_stb_o(iwb_stb_o),
    .iwb_we_o(iwb_we_o),
    .iwb_sel_o(iwb_sel_o),  
    .iwb_dat_o(iwb_dat_o),  
    .dwb_cyc_o(dwb_cyc_o),  
    .dwb_adr_o(dwb_adr_o),
    .dwb_stb_o(dwb_stb_o),
    .dwb_we_o(dwb_we_o),
    .dwb_sel_o(dwb_sel_o),
    .dwb_dat_o(dwb_dat_o),      
    .dbg_lss_o(dbg_lss_o),
    .dbg_is_o(dbg_is_o),    
    .dbg_wp_o(dbg_wp_o),
    .dbg_bp_o(dbg_bp_o),
    .dbg_dat_o(dbg_dat_o),
    .dbg_ack_o(dbg_ack_o),
    .pm_clksd_o(pm_clksd_o),
    .pm_dc_gate_o(pm_dc_gate_o),
    .pm_ic_gate_o(pm_ic_gate_o),
    .pm_dmmu_gate_o(pm_dmmu_gate_o),
    .pm_immu_gate_o(pm_immu_gate_o),    
    .pm_tt_gate_o(pm_tt_gate_o),
    .pm_cpu_gate_o(pm_cpu_gate_o),
    .pm_wakeup_o(pm_wakeup_o),
    .pm_lvolt_o(pm_lvolt_o),
    .clk_i(clk_i),  
    .rst_i(rst_i),
    .clmode_i(clmode_i),
    .pic_ints_i(pic_ints_i),
    .iwb_clk_i(iwb_clk_i),
    .iwb_rst_i(iwb_rst_i),  
    .iwb_ack_i(iwb_ack_i),
    .iwb_err_i(iwb_err_i),
    .iwb_rty_i(iwb_rty_i),
    .iwb_dat_i(iwb_dat_i),
    .dwb_clk_i(dwb_clk_i),
    .dwb_rst_i(dwb_rst_i),
    .dwb_ack_i(dwb_ack_i),
    .dwb_err_i(dwb_err_i),
    .dwb_rty_i(dwb_rty_i),
    .dwb_dat_i(dwb_dat_i),  
    .dbg_stall_i(dbg_stall_i),
    .dbg_ewt_i(dbg_ewt_i),
    .dbg_stb_i(dbg_stb_i),
    .dbg_we_i(dbg_we_i),
    .dbg_adr_i(dbg_adr_i),  
    .dbg_dat_i(dbg_dat_i),
    .pm_cpustall_i(pm_cpustall_i)   
    );  

initial begin
  $display (" --- Start --- ");
  clk =0;
  rst <= 1; 
  repeat (1) @ (posedge clk);

  rst <= 0; 
  cmd <= 0;
  repeat (10) @ (posedge clk);

  cmd <= 1;
  repeat (10) @ (posedge clk);

end

// Clock generator
always #10 clk = ~clk;

initial begin

    @(posedge clk)
    TOP_LEVEL.or1200_cpu.or1200_rf.rf_a.ce_w = 1'b0;  //Chip enable input   

end
endmodule
```

The error is as follows:

> This or another usage of 'TOP_LEVEL.or1200_cpu.or1200_rf.rf_a.ce_w'
>   inconsistent with 'net' object.

UPDATE:
The error can be removed by doing the following:

```
initial begin
    @(posedge clk)
    force TOP_LEVEL.or1200_cpu.or1200_rf.rf_a.ce_w = 1'b0;  //Chip enable input 
    #500 
    release TOP_LEVEL.or1200_cpu.or1200_rf.rf_a.ce_w;
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use `force` for an input/wire:

```
initial begin
    @(posedge clk)
    force TOP_LEVEL.or1200_cpu.or1200_rf.rf_a.ce_w = 1'b0;  //Chip enable input   
end
```

Keep in mind that `force` will hold that value until you `release` the signal.  Refer to [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf), section "10.6.2 The force and release procedural statements".  Also keep in mind that force/release should be used sparingly.